# Понимание работы с Git

Tags: git

Не могу понять один принцип работы с Git.

К примеру, дали мне задачу, я ее сделал, закомитил в новую ветку (которая от `dev`) изменения, к примеру, функционал создания новой статьи. Название ветки, к примеру, `ТС-1`.

Далее нужно делать другое задание, редактирование статьи. И сказали залить ее в новую ветку, которую я должен создать, с названием `ТС-2`.

Но у меня `ТС-2` зависит от ветки `ТС-1`. И, если я правильно понял, когда я создам отдельную ветку `ТС-2` от ветки dev, то туда попадут как файлы о создании статьи (так как проект на моем локале уже имеет данные изменения), так и файлы о редактировании. Но, правильно ли это будет? Ведь задача `ТС-1` возможно будет не верна и ее нужно изменить, тогда как быть с веткой `ТС-2`? Ее придется пересоздавать или как?

Или нужно ветку `ТС-2` делать как ветку не от `DEV` а от `ТС-1`?

Не могу понять этот принцип ветвления, вот как правильно комитить вот такие изменения как я описал выше? И что делать, если нужно изменить что-то, что я делал до последнего комита?

Попал в фирму, тут туториола никакого нету, приходится самому разбираться.

Comment: Таска закрывается когда сделана ТОЧНО и уже вливается в dev. Поэтому "Ведь задача ТС-1 возможно будет не верна и ее нужно изменить" - не может и **не должно** быть такого. Другие ветки по таскам соответственно надо от dev делать, если конечно не было принято решение разделить таску на несколько других и поэтому свои ветки сделать от неё

Comment: 1. История не линельна, это граф, в ответе ниже показывается ветвление. 2. Чтобы переделать историю, используйте `git rebase`, но в ней не переписывайте коммиты, которые уже запушены! (иначе такие изменения не примутся в удаленный репо. выкрутиться в этом случае тоже можно, но это потребует ото всех в команде перезагрузку истории, и вы получите негатив) 3. Перенос отдельных коммитов между ветками - `git cherry pick`. 4. `И что делать если нужно изменить чтото что я делал до последнего комита?` - `man git rebase` - там подробно написано.

Comment: 1. к программе *git* вопрос не имеет никакого отношения. 2. откуда в том числе следует абсолютно неинформативный заголовок. 3. вопросов задано несколько. 4. ничего похожего на «правильный» ответ дать невозможно. что и подтверждает первый же ответ (первая фраза: «Единого правильного ответа нет»). ответов (читай: советов) можно надавать вагон и маленькую тележку.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Единого правильного ответа нет. В вашей ситуации я бы создал ветку от TC1.

```
DEV[someCommit] --- TC1[commit1] --- TC2[commit2]
```

Если надо будет внести изменения в ТС1, то ветка примет следующий вид

```
DEV[someCommit] --- [commit1] --- TC2[commit2]
                             \
                              \--- TC1[commit3]
```

Если изменения также должны быть в ТС2, то необходимо сделать ребейз ТС2 на ТС1 и будет это выглядеть так:

```
DEV[someCommit] --- [commit1] --- TC1[commit3] --- TC2[commit2]
```

Comment: Понял, но в компании делают по-другому. Я создал ветку, сделал там изменения, отправил пул реквест. И теперь как бы нужно ждать пока проверят и смаржут с веткой дев. После того как смаржили, я должен сделать обновить у себя ветку дев, потом создать новую ветку ТС-2 и там уже делать другое изменение. Но ждать пока проверят нету времени, как тогда приступать работу над 2 частью, которая зависит от первой, если ее не слили с dev веткой? Ведь если я сделаю ветку от дев, то у меня ТС-1 изменений не будет, пока ее не маржут!

Comment: создавайте ветку локально